# How to disable HUD in Half-Life?

Tags: half-life

The game console doesn't detect `hidehud 1` and `drawhud 0` (or `cl_hidehud`/`cl_drawhud`)  commands, these may have worked in the past before the game was transferred to OpenGL.
"Cheats" are probably required, can be enabled with `sv_cheats 1` command.

Comment: I have to ask are you using any arguments when you are entering in any of your commands? Because I know a lot of source games require an argument in console commands.

Comment: http://www.valvetime.net/threads/is-there-a-way-to-disable-hud.143151/

Comment: @TimmyJim: I have read that thread.

Comment: @Ramirez: I have used `cl_` argument (from the thread Timmy Jim linked), editing question.

Comment: Try  hud_draw 0 it's been a while since I've played those but it was something_something.

Comment: @user598527 have you tried using those commands with either a 0 or 1 at the end of them? You do need to specify an argument when you use certain console commands to tell the command if you want that command to be true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hud_draw 0` should do the trick just fine for you.

Should you require to also remove the crosshair, then `crosshair 0` will help.

Comment: The command indeed doesn't require `sv_cheats`.